# This expression was expected to have type Async<'a> but here has type DispatcherOperation

Tags: f#, async-await

I am building a project which contains a F# file and during build there is an error on line 39:

> This expression was expected to have type Async<'a> but here has type DispatcherOperation

```
open System
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.Collections.ObjectModel
open System.Linq
open System.Net
open System.Reactive.Disposables
open System.Runtime.CompilerServices
open System.Threading
open System.Windows
open System.Windows.Threading

open Microsoft.Practices.Unity

type IActivityContext<'TResult> = interface
    abstract container: IUnityContainer
    abstract Success: result:'TResult -> unit
    abstract Error: error:Exception -> unit
    abstract Cancel: unit -> unit
    abstract RegisterCancellationCallback: callback:Action->IDisposable
end

[<Extension>]
type ActivityExtensions private() = class
    [<Extension>]
    static member StartViewActivity<'TResult>(container: IUnityContainer, callback: Action<IActivityContext<'TResult>>)= async{
        let! ct = Async.CancellationToken
        return! Async.FromContinuations(fun (success, error, cancel) ->
            let context = {
                new IActivityContext<'TResult> with
                    member this.container = container
                    member this.Success(result:'TResult) = success(result)
                    member this.Error(err:Exception) = error(err)
                    member this.Cancel() = cancel(new OperationCanceledException())
                    member this.RegisterCancellationCallback(callback: Action) = 
                        ct.Register(callback) :> IDisposable
            }
            let disp = Application.Current.Dispatcher
            Async.StartWithContinuations(
(* ERROR -> *)  disp.InvokeAsync((fun() -> callback.Invoke(context))),
                (fun()->()), 
                error, 
                cancel,
                ct
            )
        )
    }
end
```

Does anyone know why this error is coming and what is the solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message says it all: [`Dispatcher.InvokeAsync`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/Threading/Dispatcher.cs.html#d80c45dbd9e481a2) returns a [`DispatcherOperation`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/Threading/DispatcherOperation.cs) whereas `Async.StartWithContinuations` expects an `Async`.

You can await the [`DispatcherOperation.Task`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/Threading/DispatcherOperation.cs.html#0232501140388b01):

```
Async.StartWithContinuations(
    disp.InvokeAsync((fun() -> callback.Invoke(context))).Task |> Async.AwaitTask,
    ignore,
    error,
    cancel,
    ct)
```

Note that wrapping an expression with `async` will not automatically make it asynchronous and wrapping an already async flow without awaiting twice might not even execute the inner async at all:

```
let print = async { printfn "Can we observe this?" }

async { return print } |> Async.RunSynchronously // nothing printed
async { return! print } |> Async.RunSynchronously // prints message
```

So this is not asynchronous:

```
Async.StartWithContinuations(
    async { disp.Invoke((fun() -> callback.Invoke(context))) },
    ignore,
    error,
    cancel,
    ct)
```

and this might not even invoke the callback (depending on `InvokeAsync` implementation, `Task`s are usually implicitly started though):

```
Async.StartWithContinuations(
    async { disp.InvokeAsync((fun() -> callback.Invoke(context))) },
    ignore, 
    error, 
    cancel,
    ct)
```

On top, callbacks (typically the success one, here: `ignore`) might be called *before* the inner callback returns.

Comment: Why would you use `Async.AwaitIAsyncResult` instead of `Async.AwaitTask` here? The latter is clearer (most people won't know what `IAsyncResult` is) and is likely also going to be more efficient.

Comment: And using `Invoke` inside `async` will not make the code asynchronous at all. You might as well just call `disp.Invoke()` directly.

Comment: @svick thanks, I 'fixed' the `Async.AwaitTask`. The second example was meant to 'make the types match' but I should have explained that properly.

Answer (score 1):

I have got the solution of my problem.

Method "StartWithContinuations" has first parameter "computation" of type Async<'T> so i have enclosed first parameter with async{}.

```
let disp = Application.Current.Dispatcher                
            Async.StartWithContinuations(
                async {disp.InvokeAsync((fun() -> callback.Invoke(context)))},
                ignore, 
                error, 
                cancel,
                ct
            )
        )
```

Comment: This probably won't do what you want... Good idea though, inspired the edit to my answer.

Comment: This will effectively ignore the result of `InvokeAsync`, so the continuations won't be executed at the right time.